# Read ZipInputStream in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, zipinputstream

I am trying to read a zipped file using Kotlin and ZipInputStream into a ByteArrayOutputStream()

```
val f = File("/path/to/zip/myFile.zip")
val zis = ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(f))

//loop through all entries in the zipped file
var entry = zis.nextEntry
while(entry != null) {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()

    //read the entry into a ByteArrayOutputStream
    zis.use{ it.copyTo(baos) }

    val bytes = baos.toByteArray()

    System.out.println(bytes[0])

    zis.closeEntry()  //error thrown here on first iteration
    entry = zis.nextEntry
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:67)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:139)
    <the code above>
```

I thought maybe `zis.use` is closing the entry already after the contents of the entry are read, so I removed `zis.closeEntry()`, but then it produced the same error when trying to get the next entry

I know `zis.use` is safe and guarantees the input stream is closed, but I would expect it to close just the entry if anything rather than the entire stream.

Having printed the entire byte array, I know only the first file in the zip is being read during `zis.use`

Is there a good way to read all entries in a ZipInputStream in kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `use` function calls the [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#close--) method, which closes the entire stream, rather than [closeEntry()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#closeEntry--), which closes just the current entry. I think you should wrap your entire `while` loop with `zis.use { ... }`, rather than calling it for each entry.

Comment: thanks. I see where I went wrong. I had only seen examples of streams being read by wrapping it in the `use`. I didn't realize the `copyTo` method can actually be called on any input stream even outside of `use`

Comment: @backcab Can you please show what's the correct code, then?

Comment: @androiddeveloper, instead of doing `zis.use{ it.copyTo(baos) }` just do `zis.copyTo(baos)`

Comment: @backcab Oh ok. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

> Is there a good way to read all entries in a ZipInputStream in kotlin?

Here's a function to extract the files from a Zip file, which you can use as a base and adjust to your own needs:

```
data class UnzippedFile(val filename: String, val content: ByteArray)

fun unzip(file: File): List<UnzippedFile> = ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
    .use { zipInputStream ->
        generateSequence { zipInputStream.nextEntry }
            .filterNot { it.isDirectory }
            .map {
                UnzippedFile(
                    filename = it.name,
                    content = zipInputStream.readAllBytes()
                )
            }.toList()
    }
```

The key point is to use [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) to handle iterating over the entries until there are none left.

Example usage, extracing a zip that contains three text files in a directory:

```
fun main() {
    val unzipped = unzip(File("zipped.zip"))
    for ((filename, content) in unzipped) {
        println("Contents of $filename: '${content.toString(Charset.defaultCharset()).trim()}'")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Contents of zipped/two.txt: 'contents of two'
Contents of zipped/three.txt: 'three!!!!'
Contents of zipped/one.txt: 'contents of one'
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, `use` will close a resource that implements `AutoCloseable`. That means its `close()` method is called for you automatically. I think you are assuming that in `ZipInputStream`, that's been overridden to close just entries, but it has not.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html#close--):

> Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated **with the stream**. [Emphasis mine]