# How to properly iterate through all entries of a ZipInputStream?

Tags: android, kotlin, zip, moshi

On Android, I'm attempting to read a JSON file that is contained in a zip file which lives in my assets folder. The issue I'm running into is that it will throw an exception of `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` when I attempt to grab the non-existant `nextEntry` of the zipInputStream. Here is the block of code in question:

```
val awesomeList: ArrayList<AwesomeItem> = arrayListOf()

BufferedInputStream(manager.open("appData.zip")).use { bufferedInputStream ->
    ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream).use { zipInputStream ->
        var zipEntry = zipInputStream.nextEntry
        while (zipEntry != null) {
            if (zipEntry.name == "awesomeList.json") {
                JsonReader.of(Okio.buffer(Okio.source(zipInputStream))).use { reader ->
                    awesomeItems.addAll(readAwesomeArray(reader))
                }
            }
            zipEntry = zipInputStream.nextEntry
        }
    }
}

private fun readAwesomeArray(reader: JsonReader): List<AwesomeItems> {
    ...
}
```

After stepping through the code using the debugger, the error gets thrown on the line `zipEntry = zipInputStream.nextEntry` after it has iterated through each file in the zip file (there are 4). I'm using Moshi's JsonReader to read the json file, and I know that works by inspecting the `awesomeItems` object when debugging paused using a breakpoint.

I'm familiar enough with Kotlin's `use` function to know that it will automatically close a stream when it is finished, but I am not sure which stream is getting closed, when it's getting closed, and why.

I'm interested in knowing the correct way to read a zip file's entries (from Android's assets folder) using Kotlin without throwing any exceptions. Most if not all of the examples on the web are in Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read ZipInputStream in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297482/read-zipinputstream-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `use` will have closed the `AutoCloseable` by the time the function returns.

```kotlin
val input: InputStream = ...
input.use { ... }
// 'input' has been closed by this point
```

Also, when you open a `JsonReader` you are using the `ZipInputStream` as its source. That means when the JSON reader is closed so too is the ZIP stream. This leads to your error since you try to process more data from the ZIP stream after closing the JSON reader.

I can't *guarantee* this, but I believe in this case you don't have to worry about closing the `JsonReader` objects, or the `ZipInputStream` object for that matter. The object holding the "actual" resources that must be released in a timely manner is the (I assume) `InputStream` returned by `manager.open(...)`. You wrap that stream in a `BufferedInputStream` which you close via `use`, releasing any resources held by the stream. This means you should be able to remove the use of `use` with the `JsonReader` objects and your code will work (without having to worry about a resource leak).

Comment: Excellent catch. My mistake was indeed using the `.use` on the JsonReader. It was completely unnecessary and was the cause of all my woes.